# Synonym Request & Rename

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonyms

**Synonym Request & Rename**
[word](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word) & [microsoft-word](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word)<strike>, better to rename into tag:ms-word</strike>

**Rename**
[excel](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel) ==> <strike>tag:ms-excel</strike> [microsoft-excel](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel)
[outlook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outlook) ==> <strike>tag:ms-outlook</strike> [microsoft-outlook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-outlook)

Comment: I don't agree that "ms-word" is better than "microsoft-word". Why abbreviate when it isn't necessary. But "word" certainly needs to be synonymized.

Comment: @AlEveret SO uses explicitly ms-word as master tag. SU uses microsoft. Either way is OK I would say.

Comment: I have a _preference_, but it's only that. Whatever is chosen we should be _consistent_.

Comment: @AlEverett If you upvote, we might speeden up the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The request is complete. I had to remove some tags that referenced literally "word"

Comment: Muchos Gracias !!